# Responsive html: place side column between elements in main column when wrapped

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have simple columns layout:
[image: diagram-columns]

On smaller screen I want Component 2 to be the last component, placed after Component 3:

[image]

Is it possible to modify following html to meet the resposive layout criteria?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div id="component1"></div>
    <div id="component2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div id="component3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to use the [flexbox order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) in order to change the ordering of elements. As you are using Bootstrap 4, you can read [Bootstraps documentation on order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order).

As shown in Bootstrap example, it can work like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap bd-highlight">
  <div class="order-3 p-2 bd-highlight">First flex item</div>
  <div class="order-2 p-2 bd-highlight">Second flex item</div>
  <div class="order-1 p-2 bd-highlight">Third flex item</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap also has responsive variations also exist for order. For example, the class names would look like this:

```html
.order-sm-0
.order-md-4
.order-lg-2
```

Comment: but how donI make the columns im full screen?